# NullPointerException on two non-nullable LocalDateTime compare in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Android app on production reports Crashlytics shows that `isAfter()` used with two LocalDateTime causes NullPointerException.

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int org.threeten.bp.LocalDate.year' on a null object reference
   at org.threeten.bp.LocalDate.compareTo0 + 2(:2)
   at org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime.compareTo0 + 6(:6)
   at org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime.isAfter + 6(:6)
```

Our null check cannot pass any null LocalDate/LocalDateTime.

```
private fun isLastUpdateChanged(
    templatesCacheInfo: TemplatesCacheInfo?,
    lastUpdateDate: LocalDateTime?
): Boolean {
    return if (lastUpdateDate != null &&
        templatesCacheInfo != null &&
        templatesCacheInfo.lastUpdate != null) {
        templatesCacheInfo.lastUpdate?.let {
            lastUpdateDate.isAfter(it)
        } ?: false
    } else false
}

data class TemplatesCacheInfo(
    val lastUpdate: LocalDateTime,
    val templatesLanguage: String,
    val appVersion: String?
) : Serializable
```

(This code is doing a little bit too much null checks but still it does not work and causes null pointers on production)

Might be a thing: Object `TemplatesCacheInfo` is saved and retreived from local database in Android. So maybe it might be serialization problem? Used database is https://github.com/pilgr/Paper

LocalDateTime and LocalDate is from `threeten` - `import org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime`

Anyone faced this problem? Any tips on that?

Comment: Are you using proguard in production?
It is possible proguard deletes part or all of the method or code that is used by the method and that's why you're getting the NPE

Comment: In which case you'd need to add ```-keep class org.threeten.bp.** { *; }```